# Select lists are dropping-UP in IE6/6

Tags: internet-explorer, list, drop-down-menu, html-select

How can I fix the following problem with IE6/7(IE Tester) with drop-down  list(with fixed width), as it is dropping UP instead of DOWN on roll out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behavior for the Windows drop-down list control when the control is near the bottom of the screen. If the list won't fit below the control, it will render it above the control.

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I could have missed this.
By the way: is there any solution for displaying vertical scrollbar in select list for less than 30 options(as it is by default for IEs)?